# Centering the map to the devices' current location without the "center button"

Tags: android, google-maps

I did quite a bit of research on the web but I can;t find anything on this topic. Anywho, I have a map that finds the devices'current location, this is the code:

```
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

I disabled the `button` that centers to the devices' location; is there any way to center the map without the button? so when the map loads it automatically centers to the devices' location.

Answer (score 0):

So What that button does is that it find your current lat and long and fixes the map camera position as per that. If you know the lat and long of the location where you want to centre then you can use below code -

```
CameraPosition target;
latLngTemp = new LatLng(-36.84490439080399, 174.76745902901663);
                target = CameraPosition.builder( ).target( latLngTemp ).zoom( 10 ).build( );
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(target));
```

So now map on the device screen centers on the above co-ordinate

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(/*current latitude*/location.getLatitude(), /*current longitude*/location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
        .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

For the more information visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views

Answer (score 0):

You should implement LocationListener to get locations updates. In your onLocationChanged(Location location) center you camera like this

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new LatLong(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())); 
}
```

See this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) for implementing LocationListener